# Microservice Architecture: Can you eliminate the synchronous calls between services completely in a system?

Tags: microservices

Anywhere you read about Microservices, it says microservice should communicate asynchronously. It is understandable why asynchronous communication is preferred as it removes dependencies and provides low-coupling, and availability, etc.

Suppose, there is a common authorization service that is invoked every time a user calls an API. In this scenario you cannot move further util you have the response from the authorization service. Although you can call the authorization service asynchronously using Async IO, however, it is still a request/reply pattern.

Questions I have

1. Is possible to get rid of synchronous communication or more appropriately request/reply pattern in microservices-based system design?
2. Although it is possible to implement a reply/response pattern asynchronously through messaging and callbacks, which add significant overhead and latency but is it worth converting every request/reply to asynchronously?
3. If synchronous calls cannot be eliminated completely, then which scenarios it is ok to have synchronous calls among microservices?

Comment: Take a look at IAM with Okta https://www.okta.com/blog/2019/05/when-it-comes-to-microservices-identity-and-access-management-is-key/

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer for your question is: request-reply pattern doesn't mean synchronous. It can also be asynchronous. Which you already mentioned.

Long answer:

Request-Reply is just a principle. For example you send an email to a friend. The message contains data relevant to you and you are expecting a response but didn't say that explicitly. Your friend will see the email when he will get back from work and then he may or may not reply to you. Only you know that you need an answer from him.

Now there are a few options while waiting for your response. Either block your entire life until your friend responds (which will mean synchronous communication) either do something else until the response arrives in your inbox (which is asynchronous).

Now, to the point:

> Is possible to get rid of synchronous communication or more appropriately request/reply pattern in microservices-based system design?

Yes, you already have answered that at the second point. Even though it is possible I think it should be used where it is required.

> Although it is possible to implement a reply/response pattern asynchronously through messaging and callbacks, which add significant overhead and latency but is it worth converting every request/reply to asynchronously?

For the right scenario, yes. The messaging system have very good performances so the latency should not be an issue. When a latency problem occurs in a messaging system there are other options to improve it.

> If synchronous calls cannot be eliminated completely, then which scenarios it is ok to have synchronous calls among microservices?

Yes.

There is one more thing that needs to be added. Synchronous doesn't always mean blocking. In a reactive world, if you make an HTTP call to another service the caller sends the request and then awaits for the response in a non-blocking manner. When the responses arrives, the caller is notified the the response has arrived and so the process continues. While "awaiting" the CPU can do other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer might be missing the point. Authentication is a outlier in the microservices world.

You made the point that a user cannot continue until they receive their response. Correct. If you're using something like JWT they will need that token before they can access your service.

In that case, whether you call it async or not, it is a request/reply type synchronous call. Personally, I keep the authentication/identity part of separate; I accept that this will be synchronous and leave it that way. The rest of your services can and should work async and to achieve that you use a message bus, event sourcing, or some sort of async communications.

For me, there are two key things you need to identify in your system. That are services that are truly request/response and those that are truly autonomous and independent; accept those and work with it. There are no specific rules that EVERYTHING must be async and everything must use queues/buses etc.

Go with the principle that each service owns its own data and communications with the rest of your system via events/messages (not REST) and thats where the real performance, scalability and ease of deployment comes from.